# Looping through a changing event list

Tags: c, algorithm, networking

I have a list of machines that I ping depending on their response time.
Initially all machines are pinged each `t` milliseonds for 5 times. Depending on the response time for these 5 pings on each machine I adjust the time of the ping to stretch or contract it, till arriving at some configuration like this:

```
machine1: t1....t2....t3....t4....t5
machine2: t1......t2......t3......t4......t5
..
machineN: ..t1..t2..t3..t4..t5
            ^
            |machine needs to be pinged at this tick
```

`t1..tN` represents the (millisecond) ticks of the clock.

Having a thread per machine to do the ping is evident, but not an optimal solution due the number of machines.

Rather, one thread that iteratites through the global order of the events is desirable, something like this:

```
while(true){

  fetch_next_machine_to_be_pinged();
  ping_it();

  if(any_machine_pinged_5_times());
     reorder_events(); //adjust the time of its next 5 ping

  //continue
}
```

What is the best way to achieve this? (ps: language C).

Comment: Are the ping replies asynchronous?  If not, you will probably be unable to keep up with large numbers of targets.  If the replies do come back asynchronously, then you will have to match up the replies with the sends and take appropriate action.  This is beginning to sound like ping state-machines in an action- time-ordered list, somewhat as described by @aix etc.

Comment: Actually the ping replies are asynchronous, I have another thread to handle all the replies/drop them if they are too late, but for now I used a very radical option: take the GCD of all the ping events, and then sleep that time before checking if any new event needs to be triggered! this method is obviously so not optimal, but it's the simplest I could come up with

Answer (score 3):

I would use a [priority queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue).

At any time, the queue would contain one entry per machine. The "priority" of entry `M` would be the timestamp when machine `M` needs to be pinged next, and the payload would be some token identifying the machine (so that you know whom to ping).

Comment: I would use a [heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)) instead of a queue.  Heaps have much better insert complexity (`O( log(n) )`) than a queue (`O(n)`), at the expanse of a less efficient `get` (`O( log(n) )` for a heap and `O(1)` for a  queue).  This would end up in a ping complexity of 2x `O( log(n) )` --> `O( log(n) )` for a heap and `O(1)` + `O(n)` --> `O(n)` for a queue.

Comment: @jfgagne: I didn't say how the queue should be implemented, and heaps are a common way to do this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue#Usual_implementation

Comment: '@aix: true, I mixed Queue and LinkedList.